# xcode 4.3 installation for iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, xcode

Have just upgraded my iPhone to iOS 5.1 and found out that xCode 4.2 does not recognize the phone anymore. Then I proceed to download xCode 4.3 from App Store.  The download was 1.5+ GB and took a few hours.  When I came back to check the download, App Store says it is already installed.  But my xCode is still 4.2 and the 5.1 iPhone is still not being recognized.

There is a  "Install Xcode" icon in my Applications folder so I tried that.  The installer ran for quite a few minutes and seemed to have installed a new version.  But the xCode is still 4.2 after all.

So what should be done to bring up Xcode 4.3 if it has already been downloaded or even installed ?

(OS X version : 10.7.3 Lion)

Comment: How did you try to start Xcode ? If your shortcut referres to /developers there might still be the old version. 4.3 should now be under /applications

Comment: You are right, everything is ok now.  The installer mentioned should be an old installer for 4.2 and a dialogue box came out to suggest moving both the 4.2 installer and Xcode 4.2 to trash.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How did you try to start Xcode ? If your shortcut referres to /developers there might still be the old version. 4.3 should now be under /applications

Comment: Need to thank you again @HeikoG, the situation was quite frustrating until your comment came along.  Wonder if Apple mentioned anything about moving Xcode to /applications.  If it did, it was something I'd overlooked.  Now everything works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you had before Xcode 4.2, you need to uninstall this Xcode and Developer Folder. Currently I'm intalling Xcode 4.3 as well. So I will see what is going to happend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to know that there are others / somebody in a similar situation :)

Comment: I'm not, for this moment. I'm currently downloading. In this update the best feature is that we don't have to download 1.5+ GB every time. Now it's like every other application.

Comment: Agree with you, @Gatt.  It would be even better if delta update were possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will not be solved if you just downloaded and installed Xcode 4.3, you must have Xcode 4.3 + IOS SDk 5 instaaled on your system. First you have to remove older SDK and then go to apple developer where you can download new iOS sdk and Xcode. It will size about 4 GB. Once you installed all these stuffs, you can use your device for development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case it was ok.  I just downloaded Xcode 4.3.  But the iOS SDK 5 you mentioned may have already been installed when I did the Xcode upgrade.